# Uploded Video using Youtube rest API getting Failed

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube with YouTube’s REST API via Swift from ios app but I am having great difficulty figuring out what to do.  I have used following code to upload video on youtube from app.

```
func postVideoToYouTube(uploadUrl: String, videoData: Data, title: String, description: String, callback: @escaping PostVideoCallback){

    if (self.authorizer != nil) && (self.authorizer?.canAuthorize)! {

        self.servive?.apiKey = kGoogleAPIKey
        self.servive?.authorizer = authorizer

        let status = GTLRYouTube_VideoStatus()
        status.privacyStatus = "public"

        let snippet = GTLRYouTube_VideoSnippet()
        snippet.title = title
        let desc = description
        if desc.count > 0 {
            snippet.descriptionProperty = desc
        }
        var video = GTLRYouTube_Video()
        video.status = status
        video.snippet = snippet

        //  ---------------------

        let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: kAccessToken) ?? ""
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"]

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                let metadata = "{'snippet':{'title' : '\(title)', 'description': '\(description)'}}".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
                multipartFormData.append(metadata, withName: "snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
                multipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName: "demo2.mov", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
        },


            to: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet",
            headers: headers,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {

                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        print(response.result.value)

                        do {
                            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: .allowFragments) as! JSON


                        } catch {
                            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")

                            callback("", false)

                        }

                        print("Success")

                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    print("Failure")

                    callback("", false)

                }
        })


    } 
}
```

and I am getting following Response from Youtube

```
`Optional({
    etag = "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/CAh7qTdnefHn2x9Fdt7z11TW1HM\"";
    id = muradZ51g78;
    kind = "youtube#video";
    snippet =     {
        categoryId = 22;
        channelId = UCfI1223CGZiSGVKhapRfc4Q;
        channelTitle = "Khushbu Desai";
        description = Test;
        liveBroadcastContent = none;
        localized =         {
            description = Test;
            title = Video;
        };
        publishedAt = "2018-10-10T07:09:40.000Z";
        thumbnails =         {
            default =             {
                height = 90;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/muradZ51g78/default.jpg";
                width = 120;
            };
            high =             {
                height = 360;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/muradZ51g78/hqdefault.jpg";
                width = 480;
            };
            medium =             {
                height = 180;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/muradZ51g78/mqdefault.jpg";
                width = 320;
            };
        };
        title = Video;
    };
})
Success`
```

but I didn't find that video on my channel. as I am getting Video failed on youtube Studio

[Please check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1bA.png)
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally happens because of two reasons:

1. If the video is too large, then sometimes few data packets could be missed while uploading. This will result in video encoding failure.
2. It did get upload correctly but video encoding fails at the youtube end.

Few things can be checked to debug/fix the issue:

1. you have received id of the video in the response. Make a get call by Id and check if failure reason is mentioned in the response.
2. if the video file size is large then it's better to prefer [chunk](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol) upload over the multi-part upload.

Comment: Size of that video is 344KB